# setUp not initializing fields

Tags: java, junit, initialization, junit4

I attempt to initialize setup data once per class with the following approach.

```
static boolean tradeDataLoaded = false;
  static  FeedRecords  feedrecords = null;
 @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
         if(!tradeDataLoaded){
              ........
            feedrecords= .......
            }
}
```

This workaround is owing to @BeforeClass being static  - and hence not serving my purpose of initializing data from files.
However,I  notice that unless feedrecords in marked static - it is reset to null at some point in execution.
It gives a NPE while being attempted to be used in subsequent tests.
How and why is the initialized data lost - Is the test class loaded multiple times while executing tests?

Answer (score 3):

A JUnit runner may instantiate a test class every `@Test`, although it is not required to do so, which is what happens in your case. The old instance and its initialization are discarded, and the new instance created for the other `@Test` does not perform the initialization due to the static `tradeDataLoaded` being `true`.

If you want to initialize some data only once, you should avoid such workarounds and just use the `@BeforeClass` annotation:

```
static FeedRecords feedrecords = null;

@BeforeClass
public static void setUpClass() throws Exception {
    feedrecords = .......
}
```